# How can I remove or disable some objects from class in flutter to use it on another pages

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app, I made a class to use it on other pages that have the same objects, but on other pages, not all those objects on it.

```
class ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListItem(
      {Key? key,
      required this.nu_image,
      required this.en_text,
      required this.ja_text,
      required this.ja_image,
      required this.sound,
      required this.color})
      : super(key: key);
  final String nu_image;
  final Color color;
  final String en_text;
  final String ja_text;
  final String ja_image;
  final String sound;
```

How can I remove or disable it to use it on other pages has those objects on it? for examble: "ja_image".
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you simply need a question mark ? after data type like so `final String? nu_image;`. and remove the `required` keyword from the constructor. That way you can create instance of this class without all parameters needed.

Comment: yes, I do that, but not required items are still in the old class!!, I solve that by making a class for the pages that haven't all objects. Thanks for your reply man.

Comment: That's the way to do it. It follow the same principle of others OOP Languages.
Although for some cases nullable instances like @Priotr said are a good option to have :)